# dockerFile copy: Forbidden path outside the build context:

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following folder structure:

```
 - main/

     .docker-compose.yml

 - backend/

   - micro-hr/

       .dockerfile

   - rabbitmq
```

i have my micro-hr folder where is my main package
and I have a local lib which is rabbitmq

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
#create app directory
#xx
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git
RUN touch /usr/src/.bashrc | echo "PS1='\w\$ '" >> /usr/src/.bashrc
#copy files
COPY ormconfig.ts .env package.json yarn.* ./
COPY ./rabbitmq/package.json /usr/src/rabbitmq/
#install modules lib modules
RUN cd /usr/src/api/ && npm install
#copy other files
COPY . /usr/src/api/
COPY ../rabbitmq /usr/src/rabbitmq/
#set work dir
USER node
```

docker-compose :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  micro-hr:
    build: ./backend/micro-hr
    entrypoint: ./.docker/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: micro-hr
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
```

this is my package.json on my main package backend/micro-hr:

```
{
  "name": "micro-hr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm link ../rabbitmq/",
    "postupdate": "npm link ../rabbitmq/",
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "build": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir dist --copy-files --no-copy-ignored",
    "start:dev": "ts-node-dev --inspect --respawn --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts",
    "start:debug": "node start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/index.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint --fix",
    "lint2": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./ormconfig.ts",
    "migration:generate": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^9.1.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^9.1.2",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/helmet": "^0.0.48",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.13",
    "@types/pino": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/pino-http": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.1",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.8.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "pino-pretty": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.62",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tscpaths": "^0.0.9",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "amqplib": "^0.6.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "envalid": "^6.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "extendable-error": "^0.1.7",
    "helmet": "^4.1.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "pino": "^6.5.1",
    "pino-http": "^5.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "tsyringe": "^4.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know where I am wrong, basically I made the link in my main package to my lib with the npm link
and tried to create the folders in the docker, but to no avail.

error on docker build:

> Step 6/10 : COPY ../rabbitmq/package.json /usr/src/rabbitmq/ ERROR:
> Service 'micro-hr' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path
> outside the build context: ../rabbitmq/package.json ()

Comment: @KaranKumar sorry i edited the question my bad

Comment: Where is `ormconfig.json` located? as I understand it should be where the dockerfile located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `.dockerfile`:

```
COPY ./rabbitmq/package.json /usr/src/rabbitmq/
```

tells Docker to find file `package.json` in folder `rabbitmq` in main directory of the build context and then copy it to the container as `/usr/src/rabbitmq/`

This line in `.docker-compose.yml`:

```
build: ./backend/micro-hr
```

sets the build context to directory `backend/micro-hr` relative to that file.

So if your file structure is:

```
main
|- .docker-compose.yml
|- backend/
   |- micro-hr/
      |-.dockerfile
   |- rabbitmq
```

then your telling Docker to copy `backend/micro-hr/rabbitmq/package.json`, which does not exist. Furthermore your `rabbitmq` directory is not in the build context at all, sono matter what you put into the Dockerfile it will never be found.

So you should change your `.docker-compose.yml` to:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  micro-hr:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/micro-hr/.dockerfile
    entrypoint: ./.docker/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: micro-hr
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
```

and your `.dockerfile` to (I think, you did not specify where all those files are in your project)

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
#create app directory
#xx
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git
RUN touch /usr/src/.bashrc | echo "PS1='\w\$ '" >> /usr/src/.bashrc
#copy files
COPY backend/micro-hr/ormconfig.ts backend/micro-hr/.env backend/micro-hr/package.json backend/micro-hr/yarn.* ./
COPY backend/rabbitmq/package.json /usr/src/rabbitmq/
#install modules lib modules
RUN cd /usr/src/api/ && npm install
#copy other files
COPY backend/micro-hr/ /usr/src/api/
COPY backend/rabbitmq /usr/src/rabbitmq
#set work dir
USER node
```

As a side note, this:

```
USER node
```

sets user, not working directory.

Comment: my rabbitmq folder is in the backend folder
would my docker-compose have 2 builds anyway?

Comment: I fixed `rabbitmq` path in my answer. What do you mean by `two builds`?

Comment: on code u post docker-compose.yml with two build opt.

Comment: Oh, sorry. That was a typo. I fixed that as well.

Comment: i got this error : ERROR: for 2cbbc4e334d6_micro-hr  Cannot start service micro-hr: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"backend/micro-hr/.docker/entrypoint.sh\": stat backend/micro-hr/.docker/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: Entrypoint should be set to the absolute path to `entrypoint.sh` inside the container.

Comment: i try with this: ./backend/micro-hr/.docker/entrypoint.sh and continue with error.

Comment: You're copying `backend/micro-hr/` to `/usr/src/api/` inside the container, so I think it should be `/usr/src/api/.docker/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: can u helpme with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784846/docker-and-docker-compose-node-api-npm-err-code-eacces

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the context in your docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  micro-hr:
    context: . # here
    build: ./backend/micro-hr
    entrypoint: ./.docker/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: micro-hr
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
```

You always need to provide the context.