# docker and docker-compose node api: npm ERR! code EACCES

Tags: docker, docker-compose

HELLO I have the following folders structure

```
main

|- .docker-compose.yml
|- backend/
   |- micro-hr/
      |-.dockerfile
   |- rabbitmq
```

my docker compose:

```
 micro-hr:
   build: 
     context: .
     dockerfile: backend/micro-hr/Dockerfile
  entrypoint: /usr/src/api/.docker/entrypoint.sh
  container_name: micro-hr
  environment:
    - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  ports:
  - 3001:3000
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
#create app directory
#xx
RUN mkdir /usr/src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git
RUN touch /usr/src/.bashrc | echo "PS1='\w\$ '" >> /usr/src/.bashrc
#copy files
COPY backend/micro-hr/ormconfig.ts backend/micro-hr/.env backend/micro-hr/package.json backend/micro-hr/yarn.* /usr/src/api/
COPY backend/rabbitmq/package.json /usr/src/rabbitmq/
#install modules lib modules
RUN cd /usr/src/api/ && npm install
#copy other files
COPY backend/micro-hr/ /usr/src/api/
COPY backend/rabbitmq /usr/src/rabbitmq

RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/api
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/rabbitmq
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

#set work dir
USER node
```

my entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm config set cache /usr/src/api/.npm-cache --global

cd /usr/src/api

npm install
npm run start:dev
```

i got this error on docker-compose up --build:

```
micro-hr              | > micro-hr@1.0.0 postinstall /usr/src/api
micro-hr              | > npm link ../rabbitmq/
micro-hr              | 
micro-hr              | npm ERR! code EACCES
micro-hr              | npm ERR! syscall symlink
micro-hr              | npm ERR! path /usr/src/rabbitmq
micro-hr              | npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq
micro-hr              | npm ERR! errno -13
micro-hr              | npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/usr/src/rabbitmq' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq'
micro-hr              | npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/usr/src/rabbitmq' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq'] {
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   errno: -13,
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   path: '/usr/src/rabbitmq',
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq'
micro-hr              | npm ERR! }
```

and:

> micro-hr              | npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access
> to /usr/src/api/node_modules/has-symbols micro-hr              | npm
> WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
> /usr/src/api/node_modules/highlight.js

I know it's a problem with permission but I can't figure out how to fix it.
the problem is when installing my npm link modules:

```
"postinstall": "npm link ../rabbitmq/",
"postupdate": "npm link ../rabbitmq/",
```

Comment: Does your `npm run start:dev` script try to create `/usr/local/etc`?

Comment: is this:     "start:dev": "ts-node-dev --inspect --respawn --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts",

Comment: @Narigo i edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is running `npm install` as root.

Try

```
USER node
RUN cd /usr/src/api/ && npm install
#copy other files
COPY --chown node:node backend/micro-hr/ /usr/src/api/
COPY --chown node:node backend/rabbitmq /usr/src/rabbitmq
WORKDIR /usr/src/api
```

instead of

```
RUN cd /usr/src/api/ && npm install
#copy other files
COPY backend/micro-hr/ /usr/src/api/
COPY backend/rabbitmq /usr/src/rabbitmq

RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/api
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/rabbitmq
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

#set work dir
USER node
```

Based on [this article](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) I would modify my previous suggestion to:

```
USER node
RUN mkdir ~/.npm-global && npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global' && \
    export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH && \
    cd /usr/src/api/ && npm install
#copy other files
ENV PATH="~/.npm-global/bin:${PATH}"
COPY --chown node:node backend/micro-hr/ /usr/src/api/
COPY --chown node:node backend/rabbitmq /usr/src/rabbitmq
WORKDIR /usr/src/api
```

Edit:

I think this line in `entrypoint.sh` may cause the new problem:

```
npm config set cache /usr/src/api/.npm-cache --global
```

Try removing or commenting it out and rebuilding the image.

Comment: with this i got error on run npm install : > npm link ../rabbitmq/

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path /usr/src/rabbitmq
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq

Comment: maybe with i got install from my main package and not permission on my rabbitmq

Comment: from what I realized my server on src / api ran normally, but it is not allowed to install on my rabbitmq modules

Comment: npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/usr/src/rabbitmq' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq'
micro-hr              | npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/usr/src/rabbitmq' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq'] {
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   errno: -13,
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   path: '/usr/src/rabbitmq',
micro-hr              | npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rabbitmq'
micro-hr              | npm ERR! }

Comment: i tried it and it seemed to work normal until i go to my entry point and call npm install again then i have permission error

Comment: I attested now the problem is when I use npm install on my entrypoint.sh

does it have how to solve?

Comment: bro if u know about amqplib can helpme with this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813890/amqp-nodejs-connect-on-setup-api-or-on-route is about connect on amqplib